# Proof of chain rule using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, chain-rule, mean-value-theorem

Is this proof of the chain rule valid ?

We want to find the value of : $$(g\circ f)'(x) =\lim\limits_{h \to ~0}\frac{(g\circ f)(x + h) - (g\circ f)(h)}{h} \tag{1}$$

But we know from the mean value theorem that there is an $a$ in $[f(x),f(x+h)]$ such that $$g(f(x+h))-g(f(x))=(f(x+h))-f(x))g'(a)$$ so plugging in (1) we obtain :
$$(g\circ f)'(x) =\lim\limits_{h \to ~0}g'(a)\frac{f(x + h) - f(h)}{h} =g'(f(x))f'(x)$$

since when h tends to zero, $[f(x),f(x+h)]$ shrinks to $f(x)$.

Edit : from the comments, it appears that the proof is valid but leads to a weaker theorem than the usual chain-rule theorem, since the proof assumes the derivative of g to be continuous.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150264/discussion-on-question-by-aidagog-proof-of-chain-rule-using-mean-value-theorem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.